# Assignment and sequence points: how is this ambiguous?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, sequence-points

Consider the C code `a = a = a`. There's no sequence point for assignment, so this code produces a warning when compiling about an undefined operation on `a`.

What are the possible values that `a` could have here? It seems like `a` couldn't possibly change values. Is there actually undefined behavior here or are compilers just being lazy?

Comment: ... More to the point - are you just being silly? Need to put a splash more water with it.

Comment: Suppose I have a language that compiles down to C and an optimization step accidentally produces this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules of undefined behavior for sequence point violations do not make an exception for situations when "the value cannot change". Nobody cares whether the value changes or not. What matters is that when you are making any sort of *write* access to the variable, you are *modifying* that variable. Even if you are assigning the variable a value that it already holds, you are still performing a modification of that variable. And if multiple modifications  are not separated by sequence points, the behavior is undefined.

One can probably argue that such "non-modifying modifications" should not cause any problems. But the language specification does not concern itself with such details. In language terminology, again, every time you are writing something into a variable, you are modifying it.

Moreover, the fact that you use the word "ambiguous" in your question seems to imply that you believe the behavior is *unspecified*. I.e. as in "the resultant value of the variable is (or isn't) ambiguous". However, in sequence point violations the language specification does not restrict itself to stating that the result is *unspecified*. It goes much further and declares the behavior *undefined*. This means that the rationale behind these rules takes into consideration more than just an unpredictable final value of some variable. For example, on some imaginary hardware platform non-sequenced modification might result in invalid code being generated by the compiler, or something like that.

Comment: At the time the C Standard was written, the authors expected that compiler writers would interpret Undefined Behavior to mean that compiler writers were not required to shield programmers from whatever consequences their actions might cause on the target execution platform.  I've not seen any evidence that they intended compilers would go out of their way to generate useless code in cases where the behavior of straightforwardly-generated code would have been useful but the Standard imposes no requirements, but that seems to be fashionable nowadays.

Comment: @AnT Can you point out where in the standard it says that this has undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually undefined behavior. `a` can have any value at all. "I can't think of any way it can break" is not the same as "it's guaranteed to work".

Comment: Why wouldn't that behavior be defined? Just to avoid adding another sequence point to the language?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually the entire program that has "undefined behaviour" after it executes that statement.  It's not just about the value of `a` - the program can do *anything*, including go into an endless loop, print garbage output or crash.

"Undefined behaviour" really just means that the C standard no longer places any limits on what the program does.  That doesn't stop you reasoning about how a particular compiler might behave when it sees that code, but it's still not a valid C program, and that's what the compiler is warning you about.

Comment: I guess the question may be better restated as: It is obvious what the semantics of `a=a=a` should be, so what are the technical reasons for not implementing those?

Comment: @Espressofa: There's an endless list of such possible cases and no good reason to bother.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 42;
a = a = a;
```

is undefined behavior.

Sequence point rules were written to ease the work of compiler makers.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not have a rule that says “If the behavior would be ambiguous, then the behavior is undefined.” The actual rule in C 1999 at issue says “Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.”

Your code violates this rule: It modifies the value of `a`. (The note at 3.1 3 says that “Modify” includes the case where the new value being stored is the same as the previous value.)

So that is it. It does not matter whether you can figure out an unambiguous interpretation for this code. It only matters that it violated the rule. Because it violated the rule, the behavior is undefined.

In C 2011, the rule is stated in a more technical way. 6.5 2 says “If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.” When the assignment operator stores a value in an object, that is actually a *side effect*. (The main effect is that it evaluates to the value that is stored.) So this rule in C 2011 says largely the same thing as the C 1999 rule: You may not have two side effects on the same object.

Comment: I can't find that text in the C99 standard. Can you point out which paragraph you're referring to?

Comment: @skyking: The “Between the previous and next…” text is in clause 6.5, paragraph 2, of the 1999 C standard (specifically ISO/IEC 9899:1999(E)).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that you end up with the desired behavior. When somebody write `a=a=a` he probably desire `a` to be unchanged and when he writes `a=a=b` he probably desire `a` to be changed to `b` by the end of the statement.

However there are thinkable combinations of hardware and software that indeed breaks this assumption. Consider for example hardware where you have an explicit parallel instruction stream. The double assignment could then be compiled to two instructions trying to store data simultaneously in the same register. Furthermore the hardware designer could also have done the assumption that instruction pairs doing that is not allowed and could use don't-care values for those cases (and simplifying the HW).

Then you could actually end up in a situation where `a=a=a` actually changes the value of `a` and `a=a=b` ends up in `a` not being equal to `b`.