# Multiple assignment (field = Property = value)

Tags: c#, .net, properties, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Is it safe to do this in C#?

```
field = Property = value;
```

Is it guaranteed that the setter and getter be called in succession and will `field` only be assigned the result of the getter and not necessarily `value`? Will the compiler optimize it away to just `value`?

Comment: The getter on `Property` will not be called in this case. If you _need_ to have it run through the getter, you need to separate the assignment: `Property = value; field = Property;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714246/assignment-and-sequence-points-how-is-this-ambiguous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using

```
    private int tada;
    public int TADA
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GETTER");
            return tada;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SETTER");
            tada = value;
        }
    }
```

and

```
        int s = TADA = 1;
```

I only get SETTER written to the output window, so it does not seem to call the getter.

From [C# Language Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-03.aspx)

> You can even assign the same value to multiple variables, like this:
>
> int a, b, c, d;
>
> a = b = c = d = 5;
>
> In this case, a, b, c, and d would all have the value 5. This works
>   because the C# compiler performs the rightmost assignment first; that
>   is, d = 5. That assignment itself returns a value, the value 5. The
>   compiler then assigns that returned value to c. That second assignment
>   also returns a value, and so on, until all the variables have been
>   assigned.