# Infinite array C++ resizing the array with two new values in one expression

Tags: c++, templates, infinite

I have started implementing infinite array using templates in C++. Adding integers works well except one particular situation where I add two new items in one expression which required two resizes one after another (cf. below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <string.h>

template <typename T>
struct infinite_array {
    infinite_array();
    auto operator[](unsigned long long idx) -> T&;

    auto size() const -> unsigned long long;
    void resize(unsigned long long idx);

    private:
        T *data;
        unsigned long long array_length;
};

template <typename T>
void infinite_array<T>::resize(unsigned long long idx)
{
    std::cout << "Resize with idx " << idx << std::endl;
    T* temp = new T[idx];
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(T) * idx);

    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
        temp[i] = data[i];
        std::cout <<  temp[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 
    //std::copy(data, data+size(), temp);
    delete [] data;

    data = temp;
    array_length = idx;
}

template <typename T>
infinite_array<T>::infinite_array() 
{
    data = NULL;
    array_length = 0;
}

template <typename T>
auto infinite_array<T>::size() const -> unsigned long long {
    //array_length = sizeof(data)/sizeof(T);
    return array_length;
}

template <typename T>
auto infinite_array<T>::operator[](unsigned long long idx) -> T& {
    //std::cout << "Accessing element at idx " << idx << std::endl;
    if (idx+1 > size()) {
        resize(idx+1);  
    }
    return data[idx];
}

int main() {
    infinite_array<int> ar; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ar[i] = i;
    }
    // PROBLEM: ONLY ar[31] is initialized successfully to 10
    ar[30] = ar[31] = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << ar[i] << ' ';  
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't an infinite array require infinite memory?

Comment: Are you just telling us about what you're doing, or did you have an actual question?

Comment: ... and is restricted for what a `long long` can hold. Big yeah, but far from _infinite_!

Comment: If you look at the code in `main`: `ar[30] = ar[31] = 10;` is not working to set both indexes to `10`.

Comment: `**// PROBLEM: ONLY ar[31] is initialized successfully to 10**` Isn't compilable c++ code! Better you find a different way to make this clear in your question.

Comment: What do you mean is not working ...

Comment: Honest question : Isn't the compiler allowed to resolve the references in any order before performing the assignment ? Since the same array is indexed twice, and each access may resize, one of the reference might be gibberish. One way to solve this is by not returning refs directly but returning proxy objects.

Comment: @crashmstr Not if you only ever touch a finite portion of it. It's quite a frequent idiom in other languages to have lists that can always produce another element...

Comment: @cmaster yes, but an *array* implies contiguous memory/storage that is directly accessible.

Comment: @crashmstr That doesn't stop you from allocating more memory for it on an as-needed basis, does it? And that's precisely what the OP's doing. His only limitation is available memory (on a 64-bit system, that is).

Comment: @cmaster exactly! you have finite resources, so you can't have an infinite array. And on top of that, you will be unable to grow once you can't find a contiguous block of memory big enough, long before the system is out of RAM.

Comment: Thanks guys! Anyone with a suggestion how this can be overcome?

Comment: @user3329849: What do you mean "what do you mean is not working"?

Comment: Well [here](http://ideone.com/AEmxj0) it does not work, I compiled in Visual studio 2012 and it works (I actually get printed the 10 10 at the end)

Comment: @Nikos Athanasiou: Not really, take a look more closely at the output. It is just the last element that is 10.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13714246/509868

Comment: I'm looking at it in the debugger, I see the memory being assigned the number 10

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, there is no way to fix your problem, because you cannot control the order in which the calls to `operator[]` are made. And this is the problem:

- Your compiler chooses to evaluate `ar[30]` first, which will resize your array and return a reference to one of its elements.
- After that, `ar[31]` is evaluated, the array is resized again, another reference to one of the new arrays elements is returned. **The old reference still points to the element in the old array (which is deleted!)**.
- Finally, you compiler performs the assignment, assigning 10 to both elements. But since one of these elements lives in the old deleted array, you don't see it in the new array.

The simple truth is, that you must not chain calls to your `operator[]` like this, you can't work around the fact, that the compiler is allowed to perform the calls in any order.

---

Aside: It is generally a bad idea to resize any buffer on a one by one basis, the complexity of this is quadratic. Typical code uses increments of at least a factor 2. The precise factor is not so relevant, relevant is that you use a factor, because then you cut the complexity down to O(n). The value 2 is just a good tradeoff between space and time overhead.

Comment: Yes, in Visual Studio they are evaluated the other way around and it executes fine

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou UB is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you will not want to have your accessor methods (`at()` or `operator[]`) resize the array as it would violate separation of concerns (each function should do 1 thing - having it resize would require it to do 2).

The way the standard library implements `std::vector`:  If you use `at()` and supply an address out of bounds, it throws an exception (if you use `operator[]`, it is UB).

The problem you are running into with

```
ar[30] = ar[31] = 10;
```

If the size of the array must be resized, then both calls are going to have to resize it.  It is very similar to what happens with `i = i++ + ++i;` (which is also UB).  When you resize to size 31, you have a temp buffer and set the value of the new element to 10.  When you resize to 32, you have a (different) temp buffer and set the value of the new element to 10.  When the later one returns, it does not have the value of the former, so only 1 is written.  To fix it, [separate your operations](http://ideone.com/s2pXcC).

Comment: But that would require calling resize manually from time to time which is cumbersome.

Comment: I don't see how it is cumbersome to make sure that 1) you follow SoC, and 2) you don't invoke UB.  It is more cumbersome to track down a weird bug because someone invoked UB than it is to make sure you are accessing an array in bounds, IMO.

Comment: @user3329849 As a side note ... You should smack whoever taught you `auto` ... :-P

Comment: @ZacHowland Yes, it seems that `auto` just might be the new `lazy`... But I don't wanna think about it...

Comment: @twalberg Ironically, in this particular code sample, it is more typing than just putting the return value where the return value goes.  So, he worked hard to be "lazy".